# How Can I Send differents email with modal and same form with multiple button

Tags: php, jquery, email, modal-dialog

Actually this is a contact form for user who are contacts with us using different email addresses. I am going create with a modal. How can I send different email to different email addresses in modal with same form values with a single php file using jquery. There may be contrasting with same button

```
               $('.cform_btn, cform_btn2').click(function(event){ 
    if($(event.target).attr('class')=='cform_btn'){
        /* specific code for button1 */
        var mailto=$('#firstmail').val();
            var username=$('#username').val();
            var useremail=$('#useremail').val();
            var userphone=$('#userphone').val();
            var usersubject=$('#usersubject').val();
            var usermessage=$('#usermessage').val();
            var submitval=$('.cform_btn').val();
            //alert(mailto + username + userphone + useremail + usersubject + usermessage);

            $.post("contactsvalues.php",
                        {
                        mailto:mailto,
                        username:username,
                        useremail:useremail,
                        userphone:userphone,
                        usersubject:usersubject,
                        usermessage:usermessage,
                        submitval:submitval
                        },
                    function(result){

                    alert(result);



                        });
    } 
    if($(event.target).attr('class')=='cform_btn2'){
        /* specific code for button2 */
        var mailto=$('#firstmail').val();
            var username=$('#username').val();
            var useremail=$('#useremail').val();
            var userphone=$('#userphone').val();
            var usersubject=$('#usersubject').val();
            var usermessage=$('#usermessage').val();
            var submitval=$('.cform_btn').val();
            //alert(mailto + username + userphone + useremail + usersubject + usermessage);

            $.post("contactsvalues.php",
                        {
                        mailto:mailto,
                        username:username,
                        useremail:useremail,
                        userphone:userphone,
                        usersubject:usersubject,
                        usermessage:usermessage,
                        submitval:submitval
                        },
                    function(result){

                    alert(result);



                        });
    }

});

    });
```

Comment: do you want add many email address in the same field input?

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually there are three email address. When one click open a contact form in modal and user can send email. Same way as others emails address as same form structure.

Comment: do you want to send many emails that be in the same field or you have every field for every email? i think the better way is you admit to user put many email in the same field and delimited for anywant